# How to set value of range slider to value received from database in django

Tags: python, django

```
<input type="range" name="TaxRateRange" class="form-range slider" min="0" value='{{ form.taxrate }}' max="100" step="0.5" id="myRange">
```

this is range slider, trying to set value of it to the value received from the  database

here is my view

```
def insert_(request,id=0):
    taxauth=TaxAuthority()
    if request.method=="GET":
        if id==0:  #id is zero for the insert operation
           form=TaxAuthorityForm()
        else:
           obj_taxauthority=TaxAuthority.objects.get(pk=id)
           form=TaxAuthorityForm(instance=obj_taxauthority)
        return render(request,'TaxAuthority/insert.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        if id==0:
           form=TaxAuthorityForm(request.POST)
           taxauth=form.save(commit=False)
           print("######### POST Fresh Saved ##########")
        else:
            obj_taxauthority=TaxAuthority.objects.get(pk=id) 
            form=TaxAuthorityForm(request.POST,instance=obj_taxauthority)
            obj_taxauthority=form.save(commit=False)

        if form.is_valid():
            taxauth.taxrate=request.POST["TaxRateRange"]
            taxauth.save()
        return redirect('/taxauthority/')
```

Comment: what is the problem in given code it's looking fine

Comment: Are you using django form

Comment: yes ,django form , no code looks fine but it does not display value received from the database in   value={{form.taxrate}}

Comment: okay you want to display data from your database than provide your views how you are passing data to template

Comment: updated check please

Comment: you have single row data in TaxAuthority or multiple rows are there

Answer (score 0):

Try this `obj_taxauthority=TaxAuthority.objects.filter(pk=id).first()`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using  HTML or Bootstrap range slider directly on the template, we can use Django form widgets as follows

```
class TaxAuthorityForm(forms.ModelForm):

     class Meta:
             model=TaxAuthority
             #fields=['taxauthority']
             fields='__all__'
            # exclude=('taxrate',)
             labels= {
                   'taxauthority':'Tax Authority',
                   'taxrate':'Tax Rate',
                  }
             widgets = {
                     'taxrate': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'range','class':'form-range slider' 'step': '0.5', 'min': '1', 'max': '100'})
                  }
```

this will automatically create a range slider.